# $(document).ready not firing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a content script from a chrome extension injected in a youtube page.
Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("[INFO] Changes detected");
  myFunc();
}
```

When I refresh the script executes as expected. When I navigate in between pages,
`ready()` does not fire. Does this mean that the document does not change? Inspecting the
elements it obviously does.

Why isn't `.ready()` firing while navigating on a page?

Comment: Which pages, specifically? IIRC, some parts of YouTube are a SPA, so new documents don't get loaded, only parts of the existing page get replaced

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTMKdfk8fwc ; the moving to other pages by the same user.

Comment: @Sebi: Define "moving to other pages".  What specifically are you doing?  How have you confirmed that what you're doing does indeed load a new document and doesn't just update the rendering of the current document?

Comment: @David Just navigating through suggested videos; the dom does change when inspected. But doesn't an update of the rendering of the current document trigger the ready() event?

Comment: What I want to do is; if the user click on another video, the script must wait for the page to load, and then click pause on the video (it's part of a "censoring" app.

Comment: @Sebi: It seems like that's just updating the current document, not loading a new one.  Check your browser's debugging tools, specifically the network tab.  You'll see a ton of XHR requests, but no additional Document requests.

Comment: Then what could be the best way to detect changes? I thought about using a mutation observer on the url but it needs an additional delay (url changes way quicker than the page loads/updates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When navigating between `/watch?v=VideoID` videos on YouTube, you are essentially staying on the same page. *Elements* of the page get replaced with the help of XHR requests, but the *document itself* does not change.

You can see this if you open the Network tab and watch what happens when you navigate to a new video:

[image]

Notice how `document` is not any one of the request types there.

New documents are only loaded when you see `document` get requested, like in the following, where I press Enter from the address bar:

[image]

`$(document).ready(` only fires when a *new page* is loaded, not when parts of the current page get replaced with `.innerHTML` etc.

If you want to detect when parts of the page get replaced, use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Correct! But how could I detect video browsing behavior across channels?

Comment: With a MutationObserver. Identify a portion of the page that gets replaced, and a container that doesn't get replaced. Attach the observer to the container, and its callback will run when the container's contents change.